# Change Label text to what is written, when ListView as active object

Tags: c#, forms, listview, keydown

When I click on my **ListView** and write "this text!", I want my **Label** (or **TextBox** if that's easier) to change text to "this text!".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AfterLabelEdit` event:

```
private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
     yourLabel.Text = e.Label;
}
```

Don't forget to hook up the event!

If you want to display the new text while typing you can either try to listen to the keyboard between the BeforeLabelEdit and AfterLabelEdit events or you can overlay your own TextBox and use its TextChanged event.

I think this is easier but if you want to do special things, like disallowing editing key etc, it will alway mean some extra work!

Here is a short example how to overlay a TextBox over the Item:

```
TextBox EditCell = new TextBox();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //..
    EditCell.TextChanged += EditCell_TextChanged;
    EditCell.Leave += EditCell_Leave;
    EditCell.KeyDown += EditCell_KeyDown;
}

void EditCell_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourLabel.Text = EditCell.Text;
}

void EditCell_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = EditCell.Tag as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi != null)   lvi.Text = EditCell.Text;
    EditCell.Hide();
}

void EditCell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
        EditCell_Leave(null, null);
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        EditCell.Tag = null;
        EditCell_Leave(null, null);
    }
    e.Handled = false;
}


private void listView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    // stop editing the item!
    e.CancelEdit = true;
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items[e.Item];
    EditCell.Parent = listView1;
    EditCell.Tag = lvi;
    EditCell.Bounds = lvi.Bounds;
    EditCell.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;  // suit your taste!
    EditCell.Text = lvi.Text;
    EditCell.Show();
    EditCell.SelectionStart = 0;
    EditCell.Focus();
    EditCell.Multiline = true;  // needed to allow enter key
}
```

The above code works fine but as our chat has established that you actually only want to grab keyboard input and direct it to a `Label`, here is the much, much simpler solution to the 'hidden' problem..:

Start by setting your `Forms`'s `KeyPreview` to`true`. Then hook up the `KeyPressed`  event of the `Form`:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveControl == listView1)
    {
        e.Handled = true; // needed to prevent an error beep
        yourLabel.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString();
    }

}
```

This will not allow any editing and only let the label text grow. You may want to expand with a few extras, like coding for `Backspace`, if you like..:

```
  if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back && yourLabel.Text.Length > 0) 
      yourLabel.Text = yourLabel.Text.Substring(0, yourLabel.Text.Length - 1);
  else yourLabel.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString();
```

Comment: I made an AfterLabelEdit for the ListView and put the code inside like your example, but nothing happens when I type.

Comment: Do you mean nothing happens when you press enter or leave the item? It should! Or do you mean while typing? As the Name implies the event is triggered after the editing is done. AFAIK updating the Label while typing is not supported.

Comment: Nothing happens while typing, and that is what I'm after.

Comment: It would be very hard to do. If you can't get hold of the overlyed TextBox you would have to listen to all keys before they reach it and that means you would not just have to understand the input but also the editing and the navigation and the clipboard keys. Very hard. Much simpler to fake it by using a TextBox of your own you editing..

Comment: Good point. However I forgot to tell that the navigation shouldn't work. What I mean by that is that Left, Right, Delete, Backspace, Clipboard related, and so on should be disabled. Only characters that is typed should be put in the label. So I think that "listen to all keys" is the way to go here.

Comment: I have added a version that works for me. It overlays a Textbox and uses the TextChanged event..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72999/discussion-between-spunit-and-taw).